# Specify the ID of high-leverage points

Tags: r

Take a glance at the model

```
     > summary(left_int3)
     Call:
     lm(formula = Left ~ Cursor + PostCursor + CTLE + I(Cursor^2) + 
                  I(PostCursor^2), data = QPI)

      Residuals:
      Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
     -3585033  -845980   -58093   718849  4289610 

      Coefficients:
                        Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
      (Intercept)      1.455e+07  6.651e+05  21.880  < 2e-16 ***
      Cursor           2.299e-06  1.302e-06   1.766  0.07754 .  
      PostCursor       1.150e-06  2.147e-06   0.536  0.59231    
      CTLE            -4.772e+00  4.548e-01 -10.493  < 2e-16 ***
      I(Cursor^2)     -2.162e-18  6.854e-19  -3.154  0.00163 ** 
      I(PostCursor^2) -2.775e-19  5.977e-19  -0.464  0.64253    
      ---
      Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

      Residual standard error: 1175000 on 2794 degrees of freedom
      Multiple R-squared:  0.3942,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.3932 
      F-statistic: 363.7 on 5 and 2794 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

And I'd like to know it there are any observations are with high hatvalues, I used the command below, and I used 0.04 as the criteria

```
     >hatvalues(left_int3)>0.04
     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8        
     FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

And I used the command to obtain the number of True and False:

```
      > hat<-hatvalues(left_int3)>0.04
      > summary(hat)
      Mode      FALSE    TRUE    NA's 
      logical    2780      20       0
```

So I'd like to know if there is any command to know what's the ID number of these observations are "TRUE".

Comment: Could you give a reproducible example, including some data, the model and the desired output? So far I guess that "which" might be useful.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear asking. I've already edtied and hope it's clear enough now, thanks.

Comment: A "summary" is barely sufficient. The i-th hat value "hatvalues(left_int3)[i]" is larger than 0.04 if and only if "i" is contained in the vector "which(hatvalues(left_int3)>0.04)", if this is what you want. What surprises me is that the console echo shows only eight components of the vector "hatvalues(left_int3)>0.04". But the summary suggests length 2800. If I had the data and the code to reproduce the model "left_int3"
it would be a minor thing to clear up such confusion.

Comment: Thanks, the code which(hatvalues(left_int3)>0.04)" indicate the id number for me.